# is it possible to group by after a join and order by?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am just trying to group by job id and order by job is after a join. Would this be possible to would i just need to figure it out in my code?

```
  select job_id, job_status, avg_rec_time_millis from (select  
                job.job_id, 
                job.job_status,
                job_step.avg_rec_time_millis
                from job
                right outer join job_step on job.job_id= job_step.job_id)
    WHERE job_status = 'Extracted'
    Order by job_id;
```

Comment: Yes, you can. But what about `job_status` and `avg_rec_time_millis`? Do you want the max value of each one? The min value, the sum, the average?

Comment: the sum of avg rec and jobstatus should equal "extracted"

Comment: Your question would really benefit from you showing your table structure (for those 2 tables, including data types, primary keys, unique constraints and foreign keys; you can omit columns, which are not used in the query and have no part in integrity constraints), representative sample data for those tables and the query result, you would like to see for that specific data.

Comment: Some [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/5853770)

Answer (score 0):

You must group before `ORDER BY`, as in:

```
select job_id, sum(job_status), sum(avg_rec_time_millis) from (select  
            job.job_id, 
            job.job_status,
            job_step.avg_rec_time_millis
            from job
            right outer join job_step on job.job_id= job_step.job_id)
WHERE job_status = 'Extracted'
GROUP BY job_id
Order by job_id;
```

Also you'll need to "aggregate" the other columns that are not present in the `GROUP BY` clause. Any aggregation function will do: min, max, sum, avg, etc.

Comment: seems to give me a "invalid number" error. Could this because by my data or the query?

Comment: Well, you wanted to "sum the jobstatus". Is `job_status` a number? If not, then you can't sum it. Maybe "max()" will do?

Comment: As for the syntax, in one `SELECT` statement you can't do `GROUP BY` after sorting, but your query can actually be a complex query with subqueries, where a subquery does the sorting (`ORDER BY`) and the main one does the `GROUP BY`. On the other hand, it rarely makes sense, unless the main query relies somehow on the ordering of the internal query (e.g. a classic example of `ROWNUM` use, where you would like to do filtering based on `ROWNUM` value, which usually needs that). A case with `GROUP BY` on top of it rarely makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Without some samples, it may be hard to answer this, but from how I understand your case, I'd try:

```
select j.job_id, j.job_status, sum(s.avg_rec_time_millis) as sum_rec_time_millis
  from job j
 inner join job_step s on j.job_id = s.job_id
 where j.job_status = 'Extracted'
 group by j.job_id, j.job_status
 order by j.job_id;
```